# fglrx won't detect AMD Mullins R3 card on fitlet/14.04: (EE) No supported AMD display adapters were found

Tags: ati, xorg, fglrx, 3d, hardware-acceleration

I'm currently testing a [fitlet-XA10-LAN Barebone](http://www.fit-pc.com/web/products/specifications/?model%5B%5D=FITLET-GX-C67-FLAN-W) with ubuntu 14.04.2 x64. Everything seems to work just fine, but I cannot get 3d acceleration to work. "lspci -v" says the box has a

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon APU XX-2450M with R3 Graphics] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 0123
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 105
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=256]
    Memory at fea00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at fea40000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [270] #19
    Capabilities: [2b0] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [2c0] #13
    Capabilities: [2d0] #1b
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
```

dmesg | grep fglrx says

```
fglrx: module license 'Proprietary. (C) 2002 - ATI Technologies, Starnberg, GERMANY' taints kernel.
fglrx: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
<6>[fglrx] Maximum main memory to use for locked dma buffers: 3410 MBytes.
<6>[fglrx]   vendor: 1002 device: 9855 revision: 2 count: 1
<6>[fglrx] ioport: bar 4, base 0xf000, size: 0x100
<6>[fglrx] Kernel PAT support is enabled
<6>[fglrx] module loaded - fglrx 15.20.2 [Feb 27 2015] with 1 minors
```

X11 does start but both glxinfo and fglrxinfo give me

```
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  12
  Current serial number in output stream:  12
```

Looking at /var/log/Xorg.0.log shows

```
[    13.143]
X.Org X Server 1.16.0
Release Date: 2014-07-16
[    13.144] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    13.144] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-70-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    13.144] Current Operating System: Linux phoenix-fitlet 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64
[    13.145] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=ebd77b2f-3205-46a7-a21c-4394814e98e6 ro biosdevname=0
[    13.145] Build Date: 12 February 2015  11:11:26PM
[    13.146] xorg-server 2:1.16.0-1ubuntu1.2~trusty2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
[    13.146] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
...
[    13.334] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Version Identifier:15.20.2
[    13.334] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Release Identifier: UNSUPPORTED-15.20.1013
[    13.334] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Build Date: Feb 27 2015 03:27:32
[    13.334] (II) RADEON: Driver for ATI Radeon chipsets:
     ATI Radeon Mobility X600 (M24) 3150 (PCIE), ATI FireMV 2400 (PCI),
...
     KABINI, KABINI, KABINI, KABINI, KABINI, KABINI, KABINI, KABINI,
     KABINI, KABINI, KABINI, MULLINS, MULLINS, MULLINS, MULLINS, MULLINS,
     MULLINS, MULLINS, MULLINS, MULLINS, MULLINS, MULLINS, MULLINS,
     MULLINS, MULLINS, MULLINS, MULLINS, KAVERI, KAVERI, KAVERI, KAVERI,
     KAVERI, KAVERI, KAVERI, KAVERI, KAVERI, KAVERI, KAVERI, KAVERI,
...
[    13.375] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    13.375] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    13.376] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    13.376] (++) using VT number 7
[    13.376] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fglrx
[    13.510] (II) Loading PCS database from /etc/ati/amdpcsdb /etc/ati/amdpcsdb.default
[    13.522] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 248
[    13.527] (EE) No supported AMD display adapters were found
[    13.529] (II) [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
[    13.529] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    13.529] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    13.529] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    13.529] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    13.529] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    13.530] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
```

This happens when my /etc/X11/xorg.conf does not exist, or also when I use "amdconfig --initial" to make it look like this:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:0:1:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
            Viewport   0 0
            Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Interestingly, aticonfig/amdconfig detect the card as an R6.

```
# aticonfig --list-adapters
* 0. 00:01.0 AMD Radeon(TM) R6 Graphics   

* - Default adapter
```

I have already tried older versions of fglrx, I tried just installing fglrx or fglrx-updates packages in ubuntu, I tried building ubuntu packages using the AMD installer. Its always the same problem. Looking at the list of supported cards in the newest AMD release, R3 seems to be present.

I did find [this page](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=CompuLab-Fitlet-AMD-Preview) on phoronix, where it seems he used X Server 1.15.1 with fglrx 13.35.5 to make it work. But I have xorg 1.16 and am not sure how to downgrade it in order to try.

What am I missing, what else can I try??

Thanks!

Comment: This is a [fixed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1424491) as mentioned in the thread linked to in OP's answer

Answer (score 1):

D'oh. The answer can be found in the [fitlet wiki](http://www.fit-pc.com/wiki/index.php/Fitlet:_Installing_Linux_Mint_17#ATI_Catalyst_video_driver). The newer fglrx driver (15.200) seems to not support the card, which is a bug. Thus, you have to use fglrx 13.350. This is troublesome with ubuntu 14.04*.2*, since that [includes a newer xorg-abi which this old driver isn't compatible with anymore](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1424491). For me, I could work around this issue by using instructions found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2266268&page=4).

The question that remains is why my previous attempt of using 13.350 didn't work. I don't know.